# zsh crashing when editing .rs files only

Tags: shell, zsh, vim

As the title says, zsh crashes when writing to a rust `.rs` file using vim. It crashes whenever I save the file using `:w`.

It never crashes when I edit another filetype (I've tried `.c`, `.js`, `.py`). I'm guessing that it has something to do with some kind of filewatcher. I noticed it while going through the [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) exercises and have a hunch it has to do with the `rustlings watch` but I'm having trouble getting rid of this issue.

The error:

```bsh
[1]  + 1858 suspended (tty output)  vim main.rs
khuynh@kmbp:~ $ 
zsh: error on TTY read: Input/output error

[Process completed]
```

vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2019 19:03:04)
```

zsh --version

```
zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: solved my issue. was a problem with the [rust.vim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim) plugin in my `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it seemed to be an issue in my `.vimrc`, specifically with the [rust.vim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim) plugin.

In my `.vimrc`, I commented out the plugin and editing `.rs` files no longer crashes my shell!

```
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" rust plugin crashes zsh when writing .rs files
" Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
```